# In Graduation (2016), what was Eliza's intention at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, graduation-2016

In the Romanian film [Graduation (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4936450/), Eliza reveals in the final scene that she didn't cheat by marking her exam. Instead, she started crying when she ran out of time, so the examiners took pity on her and let her take extra time. She asks her father, "Didn't I do well?"

There seem to be two interpretations of her intentions:

1. Charitable interpretation - She made a conscious decision not to cheat, and things worked out for her anyway (because of her honesty and the kindness of others).
2. Cynical interpretation - She knew that she could manipulate the examiners by drawing attention to her broken arm, and leverage the same kind of "favor granting" that is exposed throughout the film (as corruption). Perhaps she even knew that marking the exam was dangerous (because of the prosecutors investigating her father), and so devised this other way to cheat.

I can't tell if the film made it purposely ambiguous, or if it's really just going for interpretation #1 and I'm reading too much into it.